# Can I set a specific return value in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection with products, and they are not all nicely formatted. Some lack data, and others are strings instead of numbers.

This behavior breaks my templating engine, I wonder if there is a fix for this.

If i just add this to the Schema:

```
order : { type: Number, 'default': 0 }
```

It does not set the value if it is not found in the collection, so I want someting like:

If `order` is not set `return 0` else `return order`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
orders.find({}, function(err, results){
    res.render('orders/index', {orders: results || 0 });
});
```